# Anaconda Docker + Tensorflow installation = Shell problem

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create an image based on the official anaconda image with tensorflow so I can run jupyter and import tensorflow from it. I've tried several permutation of the procedure

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/

https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980

But I always and up with this problem with the activation of the tensorflow environment.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
RUN apt update 
RUN apt -y upgrade 
RUN apt -y install python3-dev python3-pip 
RUN pip3 install -U virtualenv 
RUN pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN pip install pillow  
RUN conda update -n base -c defaults conda
RUN conda create -n tf tensorflow pip python=3.6
```

Running command

```
source ./settings.sh
docker stop mdsdev
docker rm mdsdev
docker run -t -p 8888:8888 \
       --name mdsdev \
       -v "$NOTEBOOKS_PATH_LOCAL":"$NOTEBOOKS_PATH" \
       continuumio/anaconda3 \
       /bin/bash -c \
       "
       /opt/conda/bin/conda init bash && \
       /opt/conda/bin/conda activate tf && \
       /opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && \
       /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=$NOTEBOOKS_PATH --ip='0.0.0.0' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
```

Running output

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

Comment: In the shell script, you need to first initialise the anaconda environment, then try activating it

Comment: Do you mean conda init bash? By adding this command first the outcome doesn't change

Comment: I just run into the same problem. `conda init bash` doesn't do the trick and concatenating bash commands `conda activate my_env` after `conda env create my_env --file my_env.yaml` with `\\n&&` doesn't help either.